# Sharing SCSS Directory Across Projects

Tags: angularjs, git, version-control, npm, sass

I am managing a project where I am using [Patternlab](http://patternlab.io) to manage the front-end styles and components, but would also like to share its SCSS directory on another Angular project that is the actual application.

Both are Git repos so my first thought was to use Git submodules, but being a Git novice I don't know if that's the best use case. I also thought about a private npm module, but not sure if that's right either.

Does anyone have experience sharing a common, version-controlled SCSS directory across multiple projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the projects can have the same version of SCSS directory all the time, it’s ok to use submodule. But usually we can’t make sure that. So submodule is not a good choice for this situation.

It’s better to manage SCSS directory in a single branch (we call `SCSS` branch here), when your project need the latest version of SCSS, you can merge `SCSS` branch into `master` branch.

Assume you want to share SCSS directory of projectA for projectB, you can use **subtree** to add `SCSS` branch for projectB. Detail as below steps (It's also suitable even you are not manage SCSS separately):

1. For projectA, create a SCSS branch to manage/develop SCSS directory separately (if you want to manage SCSS separately).
2. In projectB, add `SCSS` branch of projectA as a subtree:

`git subtree add --prefix=SCSS/ <URL for projectA> SCSS`

3. Modify/commit changes for SCSS folder in projectB.
4. If you want changes for SCSS also used for projectA, you can use:

`git subtree push --prefix=SCSS/ <URL for projectA> SCSS`

5. If you want to pull the changes of SCSS from projectA into projectB, you can use:

`git subtree pull --prefix=SCSS/ < URL for projectA> SCSS`